# Unity move file to desktop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to move an already existing file to the desktop. here's the code. basically it doesn't move the file when i play

```
    public static string GetDirectory(string tag)
    {
        switch (tag)
        {
        case "%Desktop%":
            return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void Movefile(){
        AssetDatabase.CopyAsset("Assets/Music/Background.ogg","%Desktop%");

    }
```

Comment: You need to call GetDirectory(...)

Comment: where are you calling getdirectory and movefule?  as JeanLuc says you're just saying move to "%desktop%" and not calling the getirectory (whys that static?) but, it also depends where you call it as to what happens

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the method inside the update() or start() method.

Comment: Explain more on what you mean,

Comment: Have you instantiate the method inside the update() method?. The code seem right, so I believe that the problem is on the instantiation of the method.